# Polygon on Canvas (QML) from an Numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, qml, pyside2

I have to print polygons on Canvas, but I've no idea on how to do that. The vertices of the polygons are memorized in self.__polygons that is a numpy array modified by another function.
I've tried a couple of methods, but nothing. I've commented the code to explain each function.

GG.py

```py
    class GG(QObject):

        def __init__(self, cameraIntrinsics, floorExtrinsics):
            QObject.__init__(self)
            self.__polygons = np.array

        def modArray(self):

            #function that elaborate 
            #polygon=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h]], where each [x,y]         
            #contains the coordinate of a vertice of the polygon, 
            #are the vertices of the polygon,
            #and add the latter to
            #self.__polygons, that is an array of poligons


        def drawPol(self):
            #function that draw a polygon on canvas


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
        gg = GG()
        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("gg", gg)

        currentPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        qmlPath = os.path.join(currentPath, 'try.qml')
        engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qmlPath))  

        if not engine.rootObjects():
            sys.exit(-1)   

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

try.qml

```
    import QtMultimedia 5.0
    import QtQuick 2.12
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
    import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
    import QtQuick.Window 2.12
    import QtQml 2.11
    import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
    import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3
    import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM
    import QtCharts 2.13

    ApplicationWindow {
        title: "window"
        visible: true
        id: window
        width:940
        height:510

        Rectangle {
            id: imgVisualizer
            anchors.left: window.left; anchors.top: window.top
            color: "transparent"
            width:610
            height:510
            Image {
                id: img
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: "file:///input.png"
            }

            Canvas {
                id: drawingCanvas
                anchors.fill: parent

                onPaint: {
                    var ctx = getContext("2d")

                    ctx.setTransform()
                    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

                    //print each edge of the polygon

                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.moveTo(a, b)
                    ctx.lineTo(c, d)
                    ctx.lineTo(e, f)
                    ctx.lineTo(g, h)
                    ctx.stroke()
                }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have the following considerations:

- If you are going to interact with QML it is advisable to use classes that are natively accepted by QML, for example using directly the numpy array is not appropriate, instead you should convert it to for example a QPointF array.
- The painting should not be done in python but in QML and for this you must create a property that notifies you of the change, for example create a Property that exposes a list.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import os
import sys

import numpy as np

from PySide2.QtCore import Property, QObject, QPointF, QUrl, Signal
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class GG(QObject):
    polygonsChanged = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._polygons = []

    def get_polygons(self):
        return self._polygons

    def set_polygons(self, polygons):
        self._polygons = polygons
        self.polygonsChanged.emit()

    polygons = Property(
        "QVariantList", fget=get_polygons, fset=set_polygons, notify=polygonsChanged
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    gg = GG()

    numpy_arrays = np.array(
        [[[100, 100], [150, 200], [50, 300]], [[50, 60], [160, 10], [400, 0]]]
    )

    polygons = []
    for ps in numpy_arrays:
        polygon = []
        for p in ps:
            e = QPointF(*p)
            polygon.append(e)
        polygons.append(polygon)

    gg.polygons = polygons
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("gg", gg)

    currentPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    qmlPath = os.path.join(currentPath, "try.qml")
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qmlPath))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "window"
    visible: true
    width:940
    height:510

    Canvas {
        id: drawingCanvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
            for(var i in gg.polygons){
                var polygon = gg.polygons[i]
                ctx.beginPath()
                for(var j in polygon){
                    var p = polygon[j]
                    if(j == 0)
                        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y)
                    else
                        ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y)
                }
                ctx.closePath()
                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: gg
        onPolygonsChanged: drawingCanvas.requestPaint()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Just for the record, another possible solution to get a list from Numpy could be by using ".tolist()". Is it possible to use qmlRegisterType here instead of setContextProperty?